# VS2015 C# -> How to fill Textboxes using Xml Database and Listbox

Tags: c#, xml, database, datagridview, listbox

I'm coding a little project with a simple xml Database, My C# level is low as I'm learning while I'm coding.

A part of my project consist of having a user database with name, firstname, login, password , ...

I'm using a xml database :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Personnel>
    <id>1</id>
    <nom>John</nom>
    <prenom>Doe</prenom>
    <accelvl>1</accelvl>
    <couleur>white</couleur>
    <login>john.d</login>
    <pass>123</pass>
  </Personnel>
  <Personnel>
    <id>2</id>
    <nom>Martha</nom>
    <prenom>Blue</prenom>
    <accelvl>5</accelvl>
    <couleur>orange</couleur>
    <login>martha.b</login>
    <pass>123</pass>
  </Personnel>
```

I use this code to bind the database

```
     public frm_Admin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreerDGV_P();
        GetData_P();
        CreerDataTable_P();
    }
     private void frm_Admin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
     ListGP();
    }   

    BindingList<Data_P> list_P;
    internal class Data_P
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Prénom { get; set; }
        public int AccesLvl { get; set; }
        public string Couleur { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Pass { get; set; }

    }
    public void GetData_P() //from xml
    {
        DataTable dt = CreerDataTable_P();
        dt.ReadXml(@"testbase.xml");
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            list_P.Add(new Data_P
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                Nom = dr[1].ToString(),
                Prénom = dr[2].ToString(),
                AccesLvl = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]),
                Couleur = dr[4].ToString(),
                Login = dr[5].ToString(),
                Pass = dr[6].ToString()
            });

    }
    private DataTable CreerDataTable_P()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Personnel");
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("nom", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("prenom", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("accelvl", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("couleur", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("login", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("pass", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_P.Rows.Count; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add
                (
                dataGridView_P[0, i].Value.ToString(),
                dataGridView_P[1, i].Value.ToString(),
                dataGridView_P[2, i].Value.ToString(),
                dataGridView_P[3, i].Value.ToString(),
                dataGridView_P[4, i].Value.ToString(),
                dataGridView_P[5, i].Value.ToString(),
                dataGridView_P[6, i].Value.ToString()
                );

        dt.AcceptChanges();
        return dt;

    }
    private void CreerDGV_P()
    {
        list_P = new BindingList<Data_P>();
        dataGridView_P.DataSource = list_P;
        dataGridView_P.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView_P.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView_P_CellEndEdit);
    }
    private void dataGridView_P_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        list_P[e.RowIndex].Nom = dataGridView_P[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
    private void button_new_bddp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list_P.Add(new Data_P { Id = list_P.Count + 1, Nom = "" });
    }
    private void button_save_bddp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = CreerDataTable_P();
        dt.WriteXml(@"testbase.xml");
        ;
    }

    void ListGP()
    {
        this.listBox_GP_Fichiers.Items.Clear(); // j'efface le contenu pour mettre à jour et éviter les doublons
        listBox_GP_Fichiers.Text = "";

        this.listBox_LogC.Items.Clear();
        listBox_LogC.Text = "";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Personnel");
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("nom", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("prenom", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_P.Rows.Count; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(listBox_GP_Fichiers.Items.Add(dataGridView_P[1, i].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridView_P[2, i].Value.ToString()));
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < dataGridView_P.Rows.Count; i2++)
            dt.Rows.Add(listBox_LogC.Items.Add(dataGridView_P[1, i2].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridView_P[2, i2].Value.ToString()));

        dt.AcceptChanges();
        return;
    }
```

I have a datagridview in a form and in another form I have a listbox with Name + firstname and texboxes

[this is how the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWC50.png)
         Now I'd like to fill textboxes with all the data of the selected person but is not working, when I select a name from the listbox, only the first entry of the database is shown in textboxes, here 's the code I used :

```
 private void listBox_GP_Fichiers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {

            string s = "";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Personnel");
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("nom", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("prenom", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("accelvl", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("couleur", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("login", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("pass", typeof(string));


            for (int x = 0; x <= listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                s = listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems[x].ToString();

                if (s.Equals(dataGridView_P[1, x].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridView_P[2, x].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    Var.GP_Id = dataGridView_P[0, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Nom = dataGridView_P[1, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Prénom = dataGridView_P[2, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Access_Level = dataGridView_P[3, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Color = dataGridView_P[4, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Login = dataGridView_P[5, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_MDP = dataGridView_P[6, x].Value.ToString();
                }
                dt.AcceptChanges();

                textBox_GP_Nom.Text = Var.GP_Nom;
                textBox_GP_Prénom.Text = Var.GP_Prénom;
                textBox_GP_Login.Text = Var.GP_Login;
                textBox_GP_MDP.Text = Var.GP_MDP;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried severals searches for my question but can't find anything that works for me

Thanks

edit :

Var.cs look like this

```
public class Var
    {
        //Gestion du personnel
        public static string GP_Path, GD_Path, GPQ_Path, GP_List_TS;
        public static string GP_Nom, GP_Prénom, GP_Login, GP_MDP, GP_Access_Level, GP_Color;
        public static string GP_Id;
}
```

to recreate it , Here below :

**form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreerDGV_P();
            GetData_P();
            CreerDataTable_P();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListGP();
        }


        BindingList<Data_P> list_P;
        internal class Data_P
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Nom { get; set; }
            public string Prénom { get; set; }
            public int AccesLvl { get; set; }
            public string Couleur { get; set; }
            public string Login { get; set; }
            public string Pass { get; set; }

        }
        public void GetData_P() //from xml
        {
            DataTable dt = CreerDataTable_P();
            dt.ReadXml(@"testbase.xml");
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                list_P.Add(new Data_P
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                    Nom = dr[1].ToString(),
                    Prénom = dr[2].ToString(),
                    AccesLvl = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]),
                    Couleur = dr[4].ToString(),
                    Login = dr[5].ToString(),
                    Pass = dr[6].ToString()
                });

        }
        private DataTable CreerDataTable_P()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Personnel");
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("nom", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("prenom", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("accelvl", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("couleur", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("login", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("pass", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_P.Rows.Count; i++)
                dt.Rows.Add
                    (
                    dataGridView_P[0, i].Value.ToString(),
                    dataGridView_P[1, i].Value.ToString(),
                    dataGridView_P[2, i].Value.ToString(),
                    dataGridView_P[3, i].Value.ToString(),
                    dataGridView_P[4, i].Value.ToString(),
                    dataGridView_P[5, i].Value.ToString(),
                    dataGridView_P[6, i].Value.ToString()
                    );

            dt.AcceptChanges();
            return dt;

        }
        private void CreerDGV_P()
        {
            list_P = new BindingList<Data_P>();
            dataGridView_P.DataSource = list_P;
            dataGridView_P.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView_P.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView_P_CellEndEdit);
        }
        private void dataGridView_P_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            list_P[e.RowIndex].Nom = dataGridView_P[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        }


        void ListGP()
        {
            this.listBox_GP_Fichiers.Items.Clear(); // j'efface le contenu pour mettre à jour et éviter les doublons
            listBox_GP_Fichiers.Text = "";


            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Personnel");
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("nom", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("prenom", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_P.Rows.Count; i++)
                dt.Rows.Add(listBox_GP_Fichiers.Items.Add(dataGridView_P[1, i].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridView_P[2, i].Value.ToString()));

            dt.AcceptChanges();
            return;
        }

        private void listBox_GP_Fichiers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
            {

                string s = "";

                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Personnel");
                dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("nom", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("prenom", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("accelvl", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("couleur", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("login", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("pass", typeof(string));


                for (int x = 0; x <= listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems.Count - 1; x++)
                {
                    s = listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems[x].ToString();

                    if (s.Equals(dataGridView_P[1, x].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridView_P[2, x].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        Var.GP_Id = dataGridView_P[0, x].Value.ToString();
                        Var.GP_Nom = dataGridView_P[1, x].Value.ToString();
                        Var.GP_Prénom = dataGridView_P[2, x].Value.ToString();
                        Var.GP_Access_Level = dataGridView_P[3, x].Value.ToString();
                        Var.GP_Color = dataGridView_P[4, x].Value.ToString();
                        Var.GP_Login = dataGridView_P[5, x].Value.ToString();
                        Var.GP_MDP = dataGridView_P[6, x].Value.ToString();
                    }
                    dt.AcceptChanges();

                    textBox_GP_Nom.Text = Var.GP_Nom;
                    textBox_GP_Prénom.Text = Var.GP_Prénom;
                    textBox_GP_Login.Text = Var.GP_Login;
                    textBox_GP_MDP.Text = Var.GP_MDP;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button_new_bddp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            list_P.Add(new Data_P { Id = list_P.Count + 1, Nom = "" });
        }

        private void button_save_bddp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = CreerDataTable_P();
            dt.WriteXml(@"testbase.xml");
            ;
            ListGP();
        }
    }
}
```

**Var.cs**

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public class Var

    {
        //Gestion du personnel
        public static string GP_Path, GD_Path, GPQ_Path, GP_List_TS;
        public static string GP_Nom, GP_Prénom, GP_Login, GP_MDP, GP_Access_Level, GP_Color;
        public static string GP_Id;
    }
}
```

and finally the screenshot :

[Click here to show it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5S1a.png)

Comment: what's `Var`? How's defined?

Comment: I use a separate class      : public static string GP_Nom, GP_Prénom, GP_Login, GP_MDP, GP_Access_Level;

Comment: ok... this sound pretty strange:
1) `var` is a **C#** reserved name 
2) the name of the class is `Var` but what's the name of the object of type `Var` you instantiated?

in my opinion you should avoid to create ambiguity .. .then change the name of the class to something different from `Var` and create an instance of this class with a different name from those of the class itself.

Comment: I use Var.cs  only for defining all variables of the project , I could name it Vvr instead, as you suggest it

Comment: ok ... this doesn't look as a reasonable coding style but if you feel comfortable with it that's up to you... **anyway what's the error you got**?

Comment: So I use an Xml database,  I fill a listbox with userr's  Name and first name from the database,   then when I select the name from the listbox , I'd like to fill textboxes with the other info from the xml node  ..   but  it's not working .  (sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand me )

Comment: *it's not working* is not a very descriptive report... what's the result? You got runtime errors? You got textboxes filled up with garbage? You got empty textboxes?
What you do in the code after this line?
`textBox_GP_MDP.Text = Var.GP_MDP;`

Comment: Only the content of  John Doe is displayed,  If I click on Martha Blue, John Doe is also displayed     ,  after  textBox_GP_MDP.Text = Var.GP_MDP;  , I close   }      ==> private void listBox_GP_Fichiers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   the code  }

Comment: can you update the code in your original post ? this will make things a lot easier.

Comment: Done , I also added a screenshot of the form at the end of the post

Comment: where's the code that bind datasource to xml file?

Comment: I updated the code for the database , I have page with a datagridview to see all the database content and another  page with texboxes

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the app to investigate... where did you call  `CreerDGV_P()` ?

Comment: I call it after InitializeComponent();     ,  I updated the code with the calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's the correct procedure... please note that I removed all the code lines that I found to be unrelated to your needs... you're free to reinsert them but please consider that are probably worthless.

```
    private void listBox_GP_Fichiers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            return;

        for(int x = 0; x < dataGridView_P.RowCount; x++)
        {                   
            string s = "";
            string aux = "";

            s = dataGridView_P[1, x].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridView_P[2, x].Value.ToString();
            aux = listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems[0].ToString();

            if (s.Equals(aux))
            {
                Var.GP_Id = dataGridView_P[0, x].Value.ToString();
                Var.GP_Access_Level = dataGridView_P[3, x].Value.ToString();
                Var.GP_Color = dataGridView_P[4, x].Value.ToString();

                textBox_GP_Nom.Text = Var.GP_Nom = dataGridView_P[1, x].Value.ToString();
                textBox_GP_Prénom.Text = Var.GP_Prénom = dataGridView_P[2, x].Value.ToString();
                textBox_GP_Login.Text = Var.GP_Login = dataGridView_P[5, x].Value.ToString();
                textBox_GP_MDP.Text = Var.GP_MDP = dataGridView_P[6, x].Value.ToString();              
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time , its working :)      I  searched for a paper book, maybe you can tell me if this one is a good one :  C# 6  Développez des applications Windows avec Visual Studio 2015 par Jérôme Hugon   ?   (I'm more confortable with french)

Comment: well I don't know french books but it looks like a well structured one.. anyway I will suggest you to practice over a 'free' ebook before buying an expensive paper one...

Comment: btw just another small suggestion .. when you build a data driven application try to rely on real data feeds not on copy or view of them... in this case it would be better to create a global object that manage the data taken from the xml file (a DataTable maybe) and then refer to this object from all the methods. In short you should not use datagridview as a data container.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, you are failing the search... in the code:

```
    private void listBox_GP_Fichiers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // voir si il y a du personnel selectionné
        if (listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            // si oui, affichage du résultat
            string s = "";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Personnel");
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("nom", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("prenom", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("accelvl", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("couleur", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("login", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("pass", typeof(string));

            for (int x = 0; x <= listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                s = listBox_GP_Fichiers.SelectedItems[x].ToString();
                string aux = "";
                aux = dataGridView_P[1, x].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridView_P[2, x].Value.ToString();

                if (s.Equals(aux))
                {
                    Var.GP_Id = dataGridView_P[0, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Nom = dataGridView_P[1, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Prénom = dataGridView_P[2, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Access_Level = dataGridView_P[3, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Color = dataGridView_P[4, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_Login = dataGridView_P[5, x].Value.ToString();
                    Var.GP_MDP = dataGridView_P[6, x].Value.ToString();


                }

                dt.AcceptChanges();

                textBox_GP_Nom.Text = Var.GP_Nom;
                textBox_GP_Prénom.Text = Var.GP_Prénom;
                textBox_GP_Login.Text = Var.GP_Login;
                textBox_GP_MDP.Text = Var.GP_MDP;
            }
        }
    }
```

You iterate the search over data in the datagridview N times where N is the number of selected item in the listbox... of course since you only have one item selected in the listbox you will iterate the loop just 1 time and of course this will always check against the first record stored in the datagridview .. in this case is just "John Doe"... the result is that you will never fill up textboxes with data different from that of the first row in the datagridview.

The solution is to iterate over the datagridview elements instead selected items and check against selected items.

Besides this I have a number of other reccomendation that can summarize into a "you have to study and practive a lot more". If you want I can give you some hints but I think that reading a good coding book would do a lot better.

Comment: Thanks for your recommandations, I use c# from 1 month and I try to understand it by reading source code of other people who share it .

Comment: this a good practice but I'll recommand you to approach C# in a more structured way. There are a number of good books where to learn C# coding over solid basis. Take a look there http://it-ebooks.info/

Comment: Thanks for the ebook , I'll take a look at it :)         I tried your modification, but it still show the first entry